# Backup not creating a new file

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

I run a daily backup of my database through command prompt:

```
c:\sqlcmd -H localhost -Q "BACKUP DATABASE test TO DISK='c:\test.bak'"
```

But the new backup replaces the previous backup. Please tell me what to change so that all backups will be stored on disk.

Comment: There are some existing questions with answers that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880487/sql-server-command-line-backup-statement and an article that will show how to append the date: http://www.howtogeek.com/50299/batch-script-to-backup-all-your-sql-server-databases/

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing your own backup solution, I would suggest you to look at [SQL Server Maintenance Solution](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) by Ola Hallengren.

If you want to use sqlcmd then you can do as below:

Save below file as backup.sql

```
DECLARE 
    @DatabaseName sysname = N'test_kin'
    ,@DatabaseBackupFileName varchar(255);

SET @DatabaseBackupFileName = 
    'C:\test\' + @DatabaseName 
      + REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '_') + '.bak';

BACKUP DATABASE @DatabaseName
TO DISK = @DatabaseBackupFileName with init, stats =10;
```

Then using sqlcmd you can do as below :

```
sqlcmd -S ServerName\InstanceName -i C:\YourScriptDir\Backup.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

At least a couple of choices

1. Whenever you create a backup, arrange that the backup file `test.bak` has a unique name. There are lots of ways to do this, I usually embed the date into the filename (in the format yyyy-mm-dd, e.g. 2013-06-05 for yesterday) to ensure that alphabetical order of filename is the same as chronological order.
2. Use SQL agent to schedule the backup - it will take care of the names for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an edition of SQL Server other than Express then you can use a [Maintenance Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to generate a new backup file every time a backup is made, as well as to remove old backup files if wished. Also see [Maintenance Plan Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).